# Is there anything like an isomorphic membership symbol?

Tags: notation, soft-question

Lately I found myself making up notation like $x \tilde{\in} S$, meaning "$x\in A$, with $A$ being some set, group, etc, *isomorphic* (in some sense) to $S$". I'm wondering if there is a proper notation for that (why wouldn't be? after all we have things like $\rtimes$ meaning weirder things)

Comment: I'm not aware of a notation for this. You could just write $x \in A, A \cong S$ or similar. What examples do you have in mind?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the quick comment. For example: $U(1)$ and $S^1$ are both isomorphical to the set $\{x\in\mathbb{C}^n |  x\perp T,\Vert x\Vert = 1 \}$ for any $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace $T$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Instead of writing such subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, I wrote just "$x\in U(1)$", specially because what mattered at the time was the group properties rather than the specific set itself, but I wanted to keep some record that it wasn't _exactly_ the same set

Comment: In that example you don't get a canonical group structure. What you get canonically is a free and transitive action of $U(1)$ by scalar multiplication.